# How to temporary silence mode for remote push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently working with swift and iOS to make remote push notifications for my application.
And i want to implement Sleeping Mode (temporary turn-off notifications). But I don't know the best way to do this.

Should i do this on server-side or client-side ?

What delegate or api name if do this on client-side ?

sorry for my bad english.

Thank you

Comment: You could use Parse as a sever-side backend. Simply create a PFClass and a PFObject and name the object, SleepMode. Make it a boolean and in your game retreive that object. Next, say if the bool is true, File the notification else do not. You can change this anytime you may want to. Here is a link to parse, I'll post an answer later. - www.parse.com/docs/

Comment: I'm created my apns server-side with php. Should i store user notification setting on token table, Right ? Can i do this on client-side ? I want to make Sleep Mode for 1-2 hours